# Hot to use emcconville/google-map-polyline-encoding-tool in laravel

Tags: laravel, google-maps-api-3, composer-php, polyline

Hi i have installed **emcconville/google-map-polyline-encoding-tool** in **Laravel**, with composer, but cant see any references to the extension when i try yo use it in a class.

Do i need to register the extension anywhere in Laravel?

Comment: How exactly do you try to use the class?

Comment: I use the function in a random class in my project.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to register the package as an extension, the class `Polyline` coming from the package is automatically loaded with PHP/Composer autoload mechanism, so you can use it directly in your code (as per docs):

```
$points = array(
    array(41.89084,-87.62386),
    array(41.89086,-87.62279),
    array(41.89028,-87.62277),
    array(41.89028,-87.62385),
    array(41.89084,-87.62386)
);

$encoded = \Polyline::encode($points);
```

Comment: I just get an error when trying to use the Polyline-function:

(1/1) FatalThrowableErrorClass 

'App\Http\Controllers\Polyline' not found

Comment: You need to either `use` the class, or reference it with FQCN: `\Polyline::encode(...);`. I've ammended the answer.